# Get Excel cell addresses of closest values in same range

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010, vba

I have a large spreadsheet (>15000 rows) that contains company names, locations, production numbers and latitude/longitude of the locations. 
[Example Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bMSCH.png)

I am trying to compare each latitude and longitude coordinate with all the others to find those that are within 0.01 degrees. Let's call these location collections as "areas". Then I want to get the total Sold/Day and Flared/Day for each of those areas. 
I have been attacking the matter by trying to first get the cell addresses of all the lat/long locations that are within the 0.01 degree requirement of the existing row using a formula like this:

```
=CELL("address",INDEX(AB:AB,MATCH(MIN(ABS(AB:AB-[@Lat])),ABS(AB:AB-[@Lat]),0)))
```

Or a much more complex formula:

```
=ABS(RANK([@Lat],AB:AB)-MATCH(MIN(LARGE(AB:AB,ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&COUNT(AB:AB)-2)))-LARGE(AB:AB,ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&COUNT(AB:AB)-2))+2)),LARGE(AB:AB,ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&COUNT(AB:AB)-2)))-LARGE(AB:AB,ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&COUNT(AB:AB)-2))+2),0)-1)<=1
```

Where AB is the Lat column.

But they return either #N/A or 0. Perhaps I need to use a VBA script to iterate through the lat/long comparisons. However, I am not very familiar with Excel VBA. I've copied a smaller portion of the data (<2000 rows) to another sheet to make array formulas easier to test.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a Pivot Table by selecting your data and going to Insert -> Tables -> Pivot Table. If you select just one of your data, Excel will probably guess right the range of all your data.

If you want, for example, all your companies withing a 0.01 degree requirement, drag and drop the fields Long and Company to the Rows area. The order is important, it must be first the Long field and then the Company field. Then, all you have to do is group the longitude by the 0.01 degree requirement.

There are a few ways to do it. You can go to Data -> Outline -> Group, or you can go to PivotTable Tools -> Analyze -> Group -> Group Selection, or you can right click a single item (of the Long data) and choose Group from the shortcut menu.
Either way, the Grouping box appears and Excel automatically puts the Starting At and Ending At values based on your values. All you have to do set the By to 0.01. Excel automatically groups all companies based on their longitude values, grouped by the 0.01 requirement.

Comment: While simple and elegant, this ultimately does not provide a real solution. If I make a pivot table with rows of Lat, Long, Location and Company (in that order), then sort first the Lat by 0.01 then the Long by 0.01, I seem to get groupings that are close together. But If I create the pivot table ordered Long, Lat, Location, Company and sort first the Long by 0.01 then the Lat by 0.01, I get different groups than before. From a geometry perspective I need to compare each lat/long with every other via the distance equation: ds = sqrt(dx^2+dy^2).

Comment: is it something like polar coordinates, and you want to compare the radius of each point? If so, can't you add a column sqrt(Lat^2+Long^2) and group by radius? The only problem here is that you may find wrong answers if the two positions are on either side of the meridian.

Comment: Comparing radii would not tell me if one location is near another. Thanks for your input. We have since found a different way to get an estimate of the needed data.